# Lost accent characters php

Tags: php, python, json, utf-8

good afternoon , I have a script in python to run it from PHP. The script makes a query to a database and returns a JSON object :

`[{"ESC_DEF": 0, "ESC_EJE": 2017, "ESC_FEC_PRE": null, "ESC_USU_BAJA": null, "ESC_NOM": "prueba fran 3", "ESC_SIT": "ABIERTO", "ESC_USU_ALTA": "hep68", "RONDA_ID": 1, "ESC_ORI": "Gestión Económica", "ESC_SIT2": "BORRADOR", "ESC_FEC_FRCG": null, "ESC_TPO": "PRESUPUESTO", "ESC_ORG": "1214", "ESC_FEC_ALTA": "19/07/2016 10:39:20", "ESC_FEC_FIR": null, "CRE": 0.00, "ID_PTOEGE": null, "ESC_FEC_BAJA": null, "ESC_COD_BAJA": null, "ID": 3637, "EST_ORG_NOM": null}]`

The command I use is :

```
son_output = json.dumps((my_query), default=custom_json, ensure_ascii=False)`
```

In PHP I run and pick up the result as follows :

```
exec('python3 sqlserver.py'. " ".$parametro, $output, $ret_code);
$json = implode($output);
echo utf8_encode(stripslashes($json));
```

But the content is displayed as follows :

> "ESC_ORI": "Gestixc3xb3n Econxc3xb3mica"

Accented characters are not displayed correctly .

Sorry if I did not express myself well in English .

Comment: Did you check at which step the problem occurs?

Comment: If I run the script from the terminal , the result is desired , but is the output of php which does not show the same result

Answer (score 0):

"\xc3\xb3" is "ó". In removing the slashes with stripslashes($str) you're also losing the unicode escapes and therefore only getting the weird chars instead of the small latin o you're looking for. Not well versed in php but try running without that function.

Comment: thanks for your answer , if I run as follows :
$json = implode($output);
echo($json);

I get :

Gesti\xc3\xb3n Econ\xc3\xb3mica


If I remove the following line , PHP shows nothing :

json_output = json_output.encode('utf-8')

Comment: if I run as follows : json_output = json_output.encode('utf8') , I get ESC_ORI": "Gesti\\u00f3n Econ\\u00f3mica

Comment: Ok, with some more reading, I'm going to say I was wrong on this one. codecs always gets me. Think your solution would be to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php function instead, as python already have it as utf-8 I'm guessing we don't want to encode it once again.